# Extension Method with Type Constraints

Tags: c#, .net

I have a set of user controls which are defined like so..

```
public class Control1: UserControl, Shop.Stock.IBlue

public class Control2: UserControl, Shop.Stock.IBlue

public class Control2: UserControl, Shop.Stock.IBlue
```

note there are about 200 of these and they are named better in the real project.

I want to write an extension method on objects which are based off UserControl and implement the interface Shop.Stock.IBlue

I don't want the extension method to just be of UserControl

Is there a way of doing this with out adding in a new base class?

Comment: An extension method cannot be used to implement an interface. Extension methods are only for the caller, and only at compile time: not for the actual class itself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you want to define an extension method which is only applicable to `UserControls` which implement `IBlue`.

```
   public static void Foo<T>( this T obj )
       where T : UserControl, IBlue
    {

    }
```

Comment: Yeah that is what i am trying to do. ill go give it a try

Comment: I'm getting "A constraint clause has already been specified for type parameter 'T'. All of the constraints for a type parameter must be specified in a single where clause."

Comment: Updated - that should compile (just tried it). Multiple where clauses are valid in certain conditions.